# Is there a way to solve this error when using silhouette_score with DBSCAN

Tags: python, dbscan, silhouette

I'm trying to find the best eps values for DBSCAN. I set `min_samples` to 24 as I have 2 * 12 features passed through in `x_set` but I get the following error:

`ValueError: Number of labels is 1. Valid values are 2 to n_samples - 1 (inclusive)`

I know that the `silhouette_score` requires more than 1 cluster labels. Which might be causing this error based on [similar error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382250/valueerror-number-of-labels-is-1-valid-values-are-2-to-n-samples-1-inclusiv)

How do I solve this issue?

`x_set`contains the following data:

```
x_set = [6.67933536e+00 1.65097236e+00 1.24573705e+00 1.01693195e+00
 9.28128921e-01 7.82497904e-01 5.98319768e-01 1.13439548e-01
 9.05382510e-04 5.42710767e-04 2.87522799e-04 1.90924073e-04]
```

```
def best_eps(x_set):
    
    X = x_set

    range_eps = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
    for i in range_eps:
        print("eps value is: "+str(i))
        db = DBSCAN(eps=i, min_samples=24, metric='euclidean').fit(X)
        core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
        core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
        labels = db.labels_
        print(set(labels))
        silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, labels)
        print("For eps value ="+str(i), labels, "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose parameters so that you get more than one cluster.

Also, Silhouette is not *sensible* to use on clusterings with Noise.

It will treat noise as a cluster, and assign it a very poor Silhouette.